# Div Opacity Change with setTimeout function not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change the opacity of a div for a given interval so that the object consistently pulses. The element will continually pulse until a button is pressed. The code below doesn't get the element to continually change opacity and I don't know why.

```
function setRandomZoneOpacity(){
    while(buttonpressed==false;){
        var n=randomIntFromInterval(0,1);
        var zone_string = zones[n];
        document.getElementById(zone_string).style.filter="opacity(100%)";
        setTimeout(function(){};,1000);
        document.getElementById(zone_string).style.filter="opacity(0%)";
        setTimeout(function(){};,1000);
    }
};
function randomIntFromInterval(min,max){ //random number generator
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
}
```

Comment: Have you thought about doing this with CSS animations and using JS to add/remove classes?

Comment: @ecg8 So I would just modify the CSS of each respective div for each individual pulse? (the pulses will be random but one after the other)

Comment: why do you have semi-colons everywhere?  In the `while` condition, after the `setTimeout` function?

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout is not correct

```
setTimeout(function(){ //your code here }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout(callback, delay)` does **NOT** halt script execution for `delay` milli-seconds. What it does is queue the `callback` function to be executed **after** `delay` ms.

You should either do it like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById(zone_string).style.filter="opacity(100%)";
}, 1000);
setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById(zone_string).style.filter="opacity(0%)";
}, 2000);
```

... or this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById(zone_string).style.filter="opacity(100%)";
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById(zone_string).style.filter="opacity(0%)";
    }, 1000);
}, 1000);
```